# How are artificial intelligence and Natural intelligence compared?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I can remember reading that computer intelligence is heading (or maybe the most powerful ones already have) towards the Natural intelligence of a four-year-old child. But how are the two kinds of intelligence compared?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably referring to [ConceptNet](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/) (created by the Massachusetts Institute of Technology under its Artificial Intelligence program).

It's a software system / [semantic network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_network) containing lots of things computers should know about the world, especially when understanding text written by people.

Researchers from the University of Illinois (research team led by Stellan Ohlsson) [did a study](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03390v1.pdf) on the ConceptNet 4 version of the AI and they *discovered that its IQ level is the same as that of a 4-year-old child* (somewhat... see below).

The chosen IQ test is known as the [Wechsler Preschool and Primary Scale of Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wechsler_Preschool_and_Primary_Scale_of_Intelligence) (third edition, WPPSI-III). It's commonly used in schools across the United States and is designed to measure the level of intelligence in five key categories and consists of 14 subtests (picture memory, similarities, object assembly, picture naming...).

> The  test  questions  (e.g. "Why do we shake  hands?")  were  translated into ConceptNet 4 inputs using a combination of the simple natural language processing tools that come with ConceptNet together with [short Python programs that we wrote](https://www.dropbox.com/l/JNmvkihhhT47VfdbT7rMiq). The question answering used a version of ConceptNet based on spectral methods.
>
> The  ConceptNet system  scored  a  WPPSI-III  VIQ  that is  average  for a four-year-old child, but below average for 5 to 7 year-olds
>
> [CUT]
>
> **The large variations among subtests and ordinary common sense strongly suggest that the WPPSI-III VIQ results do not show that "ConceptNet  has  the  verbal  abilities  a  four-year-old."**
>
> **Rather, children's IQ tests offer one objective metric for the evaluation and comparison of AI systems**

(From [Measuring an Artificial Intelligence System's Performance on a Verbal IQ Te st For Young Children](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03390v1.pdf) - Stellan Ohlsson, Robert H. Sloan, György Turán, Aaron Urasky)

Comment: The article I read also mentioned the number of operations per second in connection the measure of intelligence. Wich is much bigger than the in the brain of a four-year-old child (and, for that matter, a grown-up person, if you can speak about the number of operations in the brain).

Comment: I like your answer, but I would like to add something. IQ tests are rarely measuring "intelligence", they exist to measure standarized (per age range) wisdom (knowledge), and were invented to tell apart children with learning difficulties, and serving solely one purpose - attemptimg test for fun is kinda pointless. Moreover there are strict rules to repeat test - cooldown time is needed, which is (probably not intentionally) not obeyed by NN creators. "Real" tests or rather meaningful measures of ability to learn were (to my best knowledge, and Google search) not used for NN up to today.

Comment: Counterintuitively the tests are also the measure of communication skills, tests for IQ for those who cannot read exists, but those "easier" for human are currently too hard for computers. If anyone really want all the details I am available on chat or I can give answer (but I am afraid it is kinda boring and longish explaination).

Comment: @EvilJS Your comments are a very suitable integration and the topic is very interesting. I'm looking forward to reading more.